# What is the purpose of css @ selector?

Tags: css

Anyone know what the '@ page' selector in this example is for?

```
@media print {
  @    page {
        margin: 2cm .5cm;
    }
```

Comment: I believe its for print media, you can specify size: A4 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this actually should be `@page` (without the white-space).

[MDN on @page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page)

> The @page CSS at-rule is used to modify some CSS properties when printing a document. You can't change all CSS properties with @page. You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of the document. Attempts to change any other CSS properties will be ignored.

Comment: ah, makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Pages can be styled using `@page` rules, which by default apply to every page in the document. It is also possible to apply style to specific pages using page selectors.